# Changing/adding attribute to div with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that assigns `data-offset-top` and `data-offset-bottom` to an affixed (bootstrap affix) div. At least this is what I am trying to do. For some reason it does not work... anymore.

Is there something wrong with the code bellow or the issue is from somewhere else?

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var off = $(".navbar-static-top").height() + 80; 
    var off2 = $("footer").height() + 30;
    $(".awrap > div:nth-child(1)").attr('data-offset-top', off.toString(); );
    $(".awrap > div:nth-child(1)").attr('data-offset-bottom', off2.toString(); );           
    $(function() {
        var $affixElement = $('div[data-spy="affix"]');
            $affixElement.width($affixElement.parent().width());
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide a http://jsfiddle.net of your issue, and provide the full html of the page? (preferably both)

Comment: Well for one you can remove the `;` after the `off.toString()` and `off2.toString()`.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Console?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was my use of WooCommerce jQuery Cookie fix. (when I deactivated it things went back to normal). 
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

If you check the console you will most likely be seeing an error saying `missing ) after argument list`

This is due to

```
$(".awrap > div:nth-child(1)").attr('data-offset-top', off.toString(); );
$(".awrap > div:nth-child(1)").attr('data-offset-bottom', off2.toString(); );
```

Most notably the

```
off.toString();
off2.toString();
```

You can't have the `;` inside the `attr` function.